# Trying to add subform field to existing component xml

Tags: component, custom-component, custom-field, xml

I've added the following into my components XML file :

```
    <field name="activity_name" type="subform" label="Activity" description="" multiple="true" min="1" max="10">
        <form>
            <field name="activity" type="text" label="Activity Name" filter="safehtml"/>
        </form>
    </field>
```

I've then added a new column in the relevant database table.

The new field is showing in the backend of the site when editing but it's not saving to the database.

Comment: Are you able to intercept any diagnostic details between triggering of the form submission and the finish of the process? It will be helpful to have some breakpoints to isolate which methods are called and potentially which exact queries are being run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Straight forward code example to save and retrieve the data for a Subform?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/straight-forward-code-example-to-save-and-retrieve-the-data-for-a-subform)

Answer (score 0):

Your sub form itself looks ok.

- Where do you want to save the data? In a separate table?
- Did you retrieve the form data with

```
        $form  = $input->post->get('jform', null, 'array');
```

- How does your existing component know which form field(s) to retrieve and save?

### Content Plugin

I would recommend not changing the component. Instead you could programme a **Content Plugin**. Within `onContentAfterSave` you retrieve the form input, and save it in the database.

To display the saved data in the form, you could use `onContentPrepareForm` to retrieve + display the data in the form.

If you save your data in a separate database table, then you should clean up that data when you delete the original record. For that you could add a `onContentAfterDelete` method to remove the records in your own database table.